# Debugging JS in ASP.net Web form project with Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-code

What I want to do, and I don't even know if this is feasible/possible, is launch our old asp.net web solution in VSCode, simple for the purpose of debugging JS.

For years, I've used Visual Studio to develop and debug our web solution (.net asp webforms). However, I'm primarily a front-end developer (JavaScript) in particular. Recently I started using VSCode for personal projects and small web apps, and I really enjoy it.
99.9% of the time, I am writing JS/TS/CSS/HTML.

I don't even know if this is feasible. Any advice or suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Sure.  In fact, VSCode *excels* at Javascript debugging.  The specifics will vary somewhat with your specific project/specific use case.  SUGGESTION: Work through one of these (brief!) tutorials, then apply it to your own project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSMsP_Y0SQ8 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-web-applications?view=vs-2019

Comment: @paulsm4 You seem to have missed the point of the question. It's about debugging JavaScript from an ASP.NET Web Forms project using Visual Studio Code. Not Visual Studio, and not just a plain static HTML site. None of those links you provided are helpful in this scenario.

Comment: Exactly paul, however thank you both. I've been launching the solution from visual studio, and opening VSCode at the same time, and working on the files with the improved intellisense/syntax highlighting ect. I don't get debugging capabilities, and to be honest I always used Chrome Dev tools with Workspace (write to disk) anyways, but I'd love to get the number of editors I have open down to one most of time.

Comment: @mason - *ALL* of the links were *explicitly* for MS VSCode (except the last one).  The mechanics of JS debugging in VSCode are the same ... but some of the specifics will vary between say, an ASP.Net app and an Angular SPA.  I included the final link just for completeness.  If the OP *CAN* debug in MSVS... and if his app is coded with MSVS... then the OP might prefer MSVS, at least some of the time.

Comment: @paulsm4 The mechanics aren't the same. In order to run an ASP.NET Web Forms site, you need server side logic. I'm not aware of any tool for VS Code that is capable of running that server side logic. Perhaps there is, but you haven't provided a link to any tool capable of doing that. An Angular SPA runs entirely client side, and that's simple enough to spin up in VS Code. The same can't be said for ASP.NET Web Forms. If you know how, then please feel free to share that information. But the information you've shared in your prior comment does not accomplish that.

Comment: [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code) might be capable of it. You'd still have to run VS (or IIS) in order to handle the server side logic and render the site, but once you have that, then the directions in that link should help with debugging the JS.

Comment: So, for anyone whos curious, you have to spin up the app with IIS express, and attach and or config the debugger (im using chrome debugger) to listen/point to localhost/port.
I'm still learning as I go, but I thought I'd post, maybe it will help someone :)